# Google sheets - If column A & column b contain a specific word, then sum column C

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to reference two columns and then add up the matching row values in a 3rd column if both conditions are met. I.E If column A & column b contain a specific word, then sum column C

I know this has something to do with using an IF, AND statement but I've not had much luck so far...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en)

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit more, I have found lots of examples which check one condition but I haven't been able to find any that check two conditions.

Comment: The link contains an example that checks for two conditions

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at that last night but when I tried to apply it I got errors. 

I was trying to use the following but I think the placement of the commas was causing problems... 

=SUMIF(AND("E17:E33 "*Tktbox*" and "I17:I33 "*Closed"),"G17:G33","0")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robin mentioned in the comments you can use the function SUMIFS.

```
=SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])
```

In your particular example it would look like:

```
=sumifs(C:C,A:A,"Condition1",B:B,"Condition2")
```

Where here "Condition1" and "Condition2" are strings that need to be matched on columns A and B respectively to add the sum amount. You can also use numerical comparisons for example for values greater than 10, you would place in the appropriate condition ">10".

Function documentation can be found [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en).